# PostGIS: merge rasters with transparency

Tags: raster, postgis, transparency-opacity

I have two RGBA rasters with transparency, both are created with `ST_ColorMap`. I would like to combine those two rasters into one, respecting the transparency. `ST_Union` does not work, because it will stack one raster on top of each other, but will not recognize transparency.

Is there a way to merge two RGBA rasters respecting the transparency?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but isn't transparency usually just another band (alpha) ? It should be possible to manipulate this band as any other band ?

Comment: Can you better explain what are your objectives? I mean, what do you want to obtain when you merge the four bands of your two images? ST_Union is able to perform different operation when merges two rasters